# Flyway[version 9.4.0] complaining of Invalid SQL filenames

Tags: flyway

My Undo filenames are named as follows:

```
U006__DROP_TABLE_LS.sql
```

but when I run `flyway -validateMigrationNaming=true info` flyway still complains of invalid sql names:

```
ERROR: Invalid SQL filenames found:
Unrecognised migration name format: U006__DROP_TABLE_LS.sql
Unrecognised migration name format: U004__REVERT_SCHEMA_T.sql
Unrecognised migration name format: U005__REVERT_SCHEMA_T.sql
Unrecognised migration name format: U002__REVERT_SCHEMA_T.sql
...
```

What am I doing wrong? None of the `V` scripts (which are exactly the same but just with prefix `V`) were picked for having invalid script names ...

Please help!

Comment: that looks like unicode names, rename them if flyway can not handle them

Comment: if not unicode, what encoding should they be? and how did you deduce that @nbk ? Also, my file system encoding is `utf-8`. How should they be renamed?

Comment: the question is why do you have names with `U+0006  6  006  Acknowledge character  ACK / Ctrl-F` anyway, it could also be that the text file was converted into unicode by accident.

Comment: Sorry I'm being dumb, but isn't the convention supposed to be `U` followed by a number `006`? Or is `U006` the problem and it should be `U6__SOMETHING.sql` ? Also, how did you get that bit: `U+0006  6  006  Acknowledge character  ACK / Ctrl-F`

Comment: Do you have a Flyway Teams or Enterprise license? U scripts aren’t available in the Community edition.

Comment: We're using the Community edition @DavidAtkinson

Comment: I am using v10.5 and I can't reproduce this. Could you try upgrading to see if it has been fixed?